# change font awesome icon color when hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using the [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) icon plugin, but when hovering on the `<li>` element, I need its icon to change to `color: blue`. I tested, but didn't get any results so far. Can anyone help?

**Code:**

```css
.collapsedMenu__item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
  list-style: none;
}
.collapsedMenu__item span {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.collapsedMenu__item a {
  color: #dad8de;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.collapsedMenu__item:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: #2ebd59;
  transition: color .25s, background .25s;
}
.promotionLink {
  box-shadow: 3px 0 0 #6441a4 inset;
}
```

```html
<!--- Font Awesome -->
<link href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"/>

<li class="collapsedMenu__item collapsedMenu--item">
  <a class="promotionLink" data-submenu="promotion" href="promotion">
    <span><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/804jeg82/621/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following CSS code:

```
/* To use a transition for 'color'. */
.collapsedMenu__item a {
   transition: color .25s;
}

.collapsedMenu__item:hover a {
  color: blue;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** → [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/628/).

---

**Snippet:**

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */

.collapsedMenu__item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
  list-style: none;
}
.collapsedMenu__item span {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.collapsedMenu__item a {
  color: #dad8de;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.collapsedMenu__item:hover {
  background-color: #2ebd59;
  transition: color .25s, background .25s;
}
.promotionLink {
  box-shadow: 3px 0 0 #6441a4 inset;
}
.collapsedMenu__item a {
  transition: color .25s;
}
.collapsedMenu__item:hover a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<li class="collapsedMenu__item collapsedMenu--item">
  <a class="promotionLink" data-submenu="promotion" href="promotion">
    <span><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>&nbsp;Laptop</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

**Edit:**

To make it work for both **`a`** and **`i`** use:

```
/* To use a transition for 'color'. */
.collapsedMenu__item a {
   transition: color .25s;
}

.collapsedMenu__item:hover a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: ahh no , i want when i hover over <li> the icon change color as well.

Comment: That's exactly what the code does @dee cheok. Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/622/).

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @deecheok 

Comment: Angel Politis how about if add a text in <a> ? i use the same way and is not working.

Comment: It doesn't work, because you haven't added my block of code. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/626/) out.

Comment: Oh no no your code work just fine , but i added a text on <a> i want it to change the color when hover too , i use the same way , but didt work , check the new jsfiddle i post up.

Comment: Of course it won't work for **`<a>`**. The code is **`.collapsedMenu__item i`**. Since **`<a>`** isn't included anywhere how do you expect it to work ? Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/627/) fiddle and also my edit.

Comment: Don't change **`i`** to **`a`** just add the code from my edit to your code.

Comment: New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/628/). By the way, you should add your text inside **`span`**, not **`a`**. It'll work better there. Check out the snippet in my answer. You'll see for yourself.

Comment: so weird , i use the same way but my code dont work.

Comment: Check out my snippet in the answer above. You'll see that the code there works perfectly. Just copy and paste it in your project. By the way, please be sure to re-accept my answer, as I fully answered and helped you in your original question. When you have additional things you want to clarify, you can use the comments just as you correctly did. There's no need to unaccept an answer that has helped you 